# When i run the code the button unclickable

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

```
driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Driver\chrome driver\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")


sign_in = driver.find_element_by_id("button")
sign_in.click()


driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommand using Full XPath like this:

```
sign_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-button-renderer/a/paper-button")
```

instead of

```
sign_in = driver.find_element_by_id("button")
```